# Discord.JS: Multiple args for one variable

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

i`m try to make this:

`!send <id> message who sended (message who sended is 3 args but i'm need one)`

Who send arguments after message ID (args[0]) for everyone who reacted to message in DM. How make from arguments after first argument, next argument?

```
        const messageID = parseInt(args[0]);
        var messageContent = message.substring(1).split(' ');
```

I`m try this, but I'm not sure it will work.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you are trying to ask here? What is this command supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to join multiple arguments together, you can use `splice` and `join`

To begin, we need to define it as a new variable equal to args

```
messageable = args
```

Next, use splice to make a new array out of the index. If you want to make it so it is everything after the `<id>`, remove `,5`, so `.splice(2)`

```
messageable = args.splice(2,5)
```

Finally, join it into a string using `join`, adding a space in-between the arguments

```
messageable = args.splice(2,5).join(" ")
```

With this, `messageable` should look like `"message who sended"`